# How vector $[1,1]$ is same as $[-1, -1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry to ask basic question but i have some confusion
Suppose we have one vector $A=[1,1]$
and second vector $B=[-1,-1]$
Is vector $A$ is same as vector $B$ if so then how ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "same"?

Comment: It is not the same. $A= - B$. The minus sign alone implies they are unequal. However, their norms (magnitudes) are the same.

Comment: They are linearly dependent, so they are in the same "direction."

Comment: They aren’t the same, but they span the same space

Comment: They’re not the same vector. But there are many contexts in which one would “abuse notation” and say they are the same.

Comment: @VIVID when we call vector as same if magnitudes are same or if Direction are same or Both must be Same, when we call vector A=B

Comment: It is not, one is a scalar multiple of the other, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec a=[1,1], \vec b=[-1,-1]$

- They both have the same length, since $$|\vec a|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt 2\\|\vec b|=\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt 2$$
- They point in different directions, since $\vec a=-\vec b$

If you mean by "same" that two vectors $\vec u,\vec v$ are the same when $\vec u=\vec v\iff \vec u-\vec v=\vec 0$ then $\vec a, \vec b$ are not the same vector, since $$\vec a-\vec b=[2,2]\neq \vec 0$$

Comment: thanks Now it's clear

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same at all, indeed $A=-B \neq \vec0$ what is true is that they are multiple and then span the same subspace that is the set

$$S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2, x=y\}$$

which represents the line

$$P=t\cdot A=s\cdot B$$

with $s,t\in\mathbb R$.